# hangman with python invalid syntax error, visual studio code

Tags: python

just finished my first little project, a very basic single- word hangman , i'm working on visual studio code and not getting any problems with the code but when i run the program it give invalid syntax error, here's my code :

```
        secretword = "Halleluja"
lettersguessed =""
failurecount= 6
while failurecount> 0:
    guess= input("Enter a letter:")
    if guess in secretword:
     print ("good guess!, there is one or more in this word")  
    else:
     failurecount -=     print ("oops, not this letter")
     lettersguessed == lettersguessed + guess
    wronglettercount = 0
    for letter in secretword:
      if letter in lettersguessed:
       print (letter)
      else: print("_")
    wronglettercount += 1
    if wronglettercount == 0:
      break
else: print("please try again")
```

Comment: What `failurecount -= print("oops, not this letter")` suppose to do? the next line is also unusable.

Comment: Please fix formatting of the code.

Comment: That code is not understandable, all indentation is lost (I'm assuming it is right in your machine) and that is very important in Python. You should also indicate in what line you are getting the error.

Comment: Look like the first section of the code is too much indented, the part from the `secretcode` to the `while` shouldn't be indented at all and the `guess` should be on the same level as the first `if`

Comment: failurecount -=     print ("oops, not this letter")  - This line would throw an error, most probably - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I assume the cause of your problem is your indention. Please read https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aly it should be written like this. In else block, failurecount decrement isn't happening.

```
secretword = "Halleluja"
lettersguessed =""
failurecount= 6
while failurecount> 0:
    guess= input("Enter a letter:")
    if guess in secretword:
     print ("good guess!, there is one or more in this word")  
    else:
     failurecount -= 1    
     print ("oops, not this letter")
     lettersguessed == lettersguessed + guess
    wronglettercount = 0
    for letter in secretword:
      if letter in lettersguessed:
       print (letter)
      else: print("_")
    wronglettercount += 1
    if wronglettercount == 0:
      break
else: print("please try again")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however it still returns invalid syntax , I'm quite sure it's not about indentation, any ideas?

Comment: Does it say in which line has "Invalid Syntax"